# Is there a searchable list of applications that support OS X's resume/autosave/iCloud features?

Tags: macos, applications, icloud, resume, autosave

I just upgraded to Lion and I'd like to know what applications support OS X's resume/autosave/iCloud features. Is there a searchable list of applications that support these features?

Update: This question also includes Mountain Lion.

Comment: This list is going to be quite hard to assemble since although apps can declare whether they support [Sudden Termination and Automatic Termination](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW27) in the Info.plist they also can dynamically turn on and off these two behaviors as the program runs. In practice, you can see the current status as an optional field in Activity Monitor to inspect the status of apps in real time on your mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the [Roaring Apps](http://roaringapps.com/) developer and he has added this feature to his tables:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that there is a resource showing apps that support one specific Lion feature; but an excellent starter source is Roaring Apps: [http://roaringapps.com](http://roaringapps.com/).

Roaring apps is a group sourced site that analyses apps and how well they do or don't work on Lion. This site had a lot more traffic right after Lion's release and I expect it to get hit again as (Redacted) Lion hits the streets.

It might be worth submitting to that site to see if they'd expand to cover Lion-esque features for more details.